# Serve static file with express on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

Here are my files organisation :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Wdx8mKf.png]

And i would like to serve the file in vr/build in a static way with express on heroku.

here is my code in app.js  :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
//app.use(express.static(__dirname)); // Current directory is root
app.use(express.static(path.join(process.env.PWD, 'vr/build'))); //  "public" off of current is root


app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port 8080');
```

It works locally but doesn't seems to work on heroku i have a 
Cannot GET / error on heroku.

If anyone have any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work in theory but unless you try it you'll never know.

```
app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD+"/build"));
app.get("/build",function() {});
```